# How to read specific word of a text file in Python

Tags: python-2.x

Output.txt = report_fail_20150818_13_23.txt

I want to read output.txt from 8th character to 11th so that it can print fail.

```
fo = open("output.txt", "r+")
str = fo.read(8,11);
print "Read String is : ", str
fo.close()
```

Comment: what's the error/output?

Comment: Use `fo.seek`, but you might need to open using binary access, particularly on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the line first, then get the word from that line. Use the `.readline()` method ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline)).

Here is the correct way according to the example in the question:

```
fo = open("output.txt", "r+")
str = fo.readline()
str = str[7:11]
print "Read String is : ", str
fo.close()
```

However, for the best practise use a `with` statement:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as fo:
    str = fo.readline()
    str = str[7:11]
    print "Read String is : ", str
```

`with` automatically closes the file when the block ends.  If you are using Python 2.5 or lower, you have to include `from __future__ import with_statement`.

Comment: Please show how to use `with` (best practice for opening/closing files)